# How do I randomly select an item from a list

Tags: python, random

This is a Raspberry Pi Sense Hat project. I will post the code below but heres what it is supposed to do:

The sense hat is a grid of 8x8 LEDs (although i am using a digital emulator version onscreen) I have written a dice roller program, and so far I have the 6 numbers coded, and I have them flashing/playing through in an animation (to simulate a rolling effect) I now want to add a random.choice() to display one of the 6 numbers randomly at the end.

My problem: The method I know only really works for a very simple list, eg:

```
mylist = ['choiceA', 'choiceB', 'choiceC']
```

and using:

```
print(random.choice(mylist))
```

My version doesn't have the quotes because I dont want to print 'choiceA' as it is written in the list, choiceA is a variable containing more code.

I am going to post the whole program so you can see exactly what I am doing...apologies if its a bit lengthy for a question on here, and it may not be the most professional method of coding as I am learning the hard way...by myself

NOTE: the very last line of code is my idea of how I thought it would work. it is commented:

```
from sense_emu import SenseHat
import random
import time

sense = SenseHat()

b = [0,255,255]
w = [255,255,255]

# Number 1
imageA = [
w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,
w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,
w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,
w,w,w,b,b,w,w,w,
w,w,w,b,b,w,w,w,
w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,
w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,
w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w
]

# Number 2
imageB = [
w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,
w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,
w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,
w,b,b,w,w,b,b,w,
w,b,b,w,w,b,b,w,
w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,
w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,
w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w
]

# Number 3
imageC = [
w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,
w,w,w,b,b,w,w,w,
w,w,w,b,b,w,w,w,
w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,
w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,
w,b,b,w,w,b,b,w,
w,b,b,w,w,b,b,w,
w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w
]

# Number 4
imageD = [
w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,
w,b,b,w,w,b,b,w,
w,b,b,w,w,b,b,w,
w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,
w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,
w,b,b,w,w,b,b,w,
w,b,b,w,w,b,b,w,
w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w
]

# Number 5
imageE = [
b,b,w,w,w,w,b,b,
b,b,w,w,w,w,b,b,
w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,
w,w,w,b,b,w,w,w,
w,w,w,b,b,w,w,w,
w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,
b,b,w,w,w,w,b,b,
b,b,w,w,w,w,b,b
]

# Number 6
imageF = [
w,b,b,w,w,b,b,w,
w,b,b,w,w,b,b,w,
w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,
w,b,b,w,w,b,b,w,
w,b,b,w,w,b,b,w,
w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,
w,b,b,w,w,b,b,w,
w,b,b,w,w,b,b,w]

diceList = [imageA, imageB, imageC, imageD, imageE, imageF]

while True:
    for image in diceList:
        sense.set_pixels(image)
        time.sleep(0.1)

#sense.set_pixels(random.choice(dicelist))
```

If I un-comment the last line, the animation still keeps playing through, it doesn't display my random choice

NOTE: This code will run on the sensehat emulator website but the import id slightly different (Im running my emulator from Raspbian OS):

https://trinket.io/sense-hat

If you did want to try it out on the site,I am 99% certain you need to edit the first import to this:

```
from sense_hat import SenseHat
```

Comment: If you uncomment the last line, it will be never executed anyway, because `while True`.

Answer (score 1):

Just do:

```
while True:
    sense.set_pixels(random.choice(dicelist))
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

without the for loop

**EDIT:**

As I understand you want to first display an animation of 6 sides and then  show one side as a result of the throw.

Use a for loop with `random.choice` to show a random animation:

```
for i in range(6):
    sense.set_pixels(random.choice(dicelist))
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

If you want the animation to show all the 6 sides in random order (instead of 6 random sides) use `np.random.permutation`

```
my_permutation = np.random.permutation(6)
for i in my_permutation:
    sense.set_pixels(dicelist[i])
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: all I want to do is 1: play the through the 6 images to simulate a rolling effect.   2: stop the loop, and then display 1 of the images at random - like a dice. I have 2 programs, one does the animation (rolling) nicely, and another does the random image nicely.....my problem is combining the 2. as simple as it seems nothing is working. I also tried using "break" to stop the loop and then display my image....guess what, no joy. Python is so powerful, yet sometimes the simplest of things seem impossible

Comment: You want to display the 6 sides in random order or display 6 random sides? Note that `random.choice` does the latter, so some sides might show more than once and others not show at all.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding the question, you just want a random element from the list. This is pretty simple:

```
import random
randomIndex = random.randint(0, len(diceList) - 1)
randomDice = diceList[randomIndex]
```

Comment: That's a random index.

Comment: simple if you know how that is. and it does run without the last comment, but it only plays the sequence of images repeatedly, and thanks I will try this right away

Comment: You can use `random.choice` instead of reimplementing it.

Comment: it is still playing through the animation, no errors though

Comment: I am using this but no still joy:   sense.set_pixels(random.choice(diceList))

Comment: if I remove the "while True" loop I can easily get it to display one of the images randomly, i just can't get it to play the images in a sequence (to simulate rolling) and then display one random number...its really odd